# ¿Cómo unir varios data frames (que están en una lista) en R?

Tags: r

Tengo los siguientes 3 data frames:

```
df1<-data.frame(id=1:2, valor=c(10,20))
df2<-data.frame(id=2:3, valor=c("15","30"))
df3<-data.frame(id=4:5, valor=c(100,400))
```

Los quiero juntar, con un `rbind()`

Por lo que los agrupo en una lista para luego aplicar la función `do.call()`

```
listap<-list(df1, df2, df3)

do.call(rbind, listap)

 id valor
  1    10
  2    20
  2    15
  3    30
  4   100
  5   400
```

El resultado es el esperado, pero al querer hacerlo con el paquete `purrr`

Me arroja el error lógico de que las columnas son de distinta clase (numérico y caracter).

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(listap, rbind)
```

Entiendo que do.call() usa `rbind()`, pero la función `map_dfr()` usa `bind_rows()` para unirlos. Y la limitante de `bind_rows()` es que las columnas tengan la misma clase.

Entonces, me surge la duda, ¿Cómo podría cambiar la clase de la columna `valor` del `df2` que está dentro de la lista? Para que pueda unirlos con la función `map_dfr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes una confusión en pensar que: `do.call(rbind, listap)` es equivalente a `map_dfr(listap, rbind)` cuando en realidad son muy distintas construcciones. El `do.call(funcion, lista)` construye dinamicamente un clausula como ésta: `funcion(lista[[1]], lista[[2]], ...)`. En tu caso sería básicamente como si hubieras hecho:

```
rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Por otro lado `map_dfr()` itera sobre una lista, aplicando una función dada y finalmente uniendo todo en un solo `data.frame` mediante la función `bind_rows()`. En tu caso `rbind` es la función que se aplicaría a cada `data.frame` de manera individual, lo cual no hace nada en sí y solo colabora para que la clausula de `map_dfr()` sea completa, la unión de cada elemento no la hace ésta función sino la propia `map_dfr()` invocando a `bind_rows()`.

La comparación que deberías hacer en todo caso sería entre `do.call(rbind, listap)` y `bind_rows(listap)`. Y aquí es dónde realmente estaría el problema: `bind_rows()` es estricta en cuanto al tipo de dato de cada columna de cada `data.frame`, por el contrario, `rbind` es más laxa y promueve los diferentes tipos de cada columna al tipo más general. En tu caso, las columnas numéricas se promueven a `character`.

Este es uno de esos casos en que R base resulta mucho más cómodo de usar. De otra forma deberías: 1) unificar los tipos de cada columna previamente 2) Utilizar `bind_rows()` para unir los elementos individuales.

Una forma no del todo inteligente pero sí bien genérica, sería convertir todo a un `character`:

```
listap %>% 
  map(~mutate_all(.x, as.character)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

O si quieres convertir una columna en particular:

```
listap %>% 
  map(~mutate_at(.x, "valor", as.character)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Me quedó claro, muchas gracias Patricio. Una consulta ¿hay un forma de aplicarle una función a una determinada columna de cada uno de los data frames de la lista? Por ejemplo, aplicarle `as.character()` a la  columna `valor` de los 3 data frames.

Comment: Si, verifica mi última edición

Comment: Excelente. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

espero pueda ayudarte a lo que necesitas, el problema que presentas se debe a que los tipos de valores que estan en los data frames son diferentes, especialmente en df3, la columna valor es de tipo **chr**.
Te propongo que conviertas esa columna a numerico como los demas:

```
df2$valor <- as.numeric(df2$valor)
```

o bien de inicio cambiar el nombre de la columna desde el inicio:

```
df1<-data.frame(id=1:2, valor=c(10,20))
df2<-data.frame(id=2:3, x=c("15","30"))
df3<-data.frame(id=4:5, valor=c(100,400))
```

y posteriormente ejecutar ***map_dfr()***

```
> map_dfr(list(df1, df2, df3), bind_rows)
  id valor    x
1  1    10 <NA>
2  2    20 <NA>
3  2    NA   15
4  3    NA   30
5  4   100 <NA>
6  5   400 <NA>
```

tendrías estos resultados.

en el caso de pasarlo como numérico la segunda columna seria esto:

```
df1<-data.frame(id=1:2, valor=c(10,20))
df2<-data.frame(id=2:3, valor=c("15","30"))
df3<-data.frame(id=4:5, valor=c(100,400))

df2$valor <- as.numeric(df2$valor)

map_dfr(list(df1, df2, df3), rbind)
```

el resultado a obtener seria esto

```
> map_dfr(list(df1, df2, df3), rbind)
  id valor
1  1    10
2  2    20
3  2    15
4  3    30
5  4   100
6  5   400
```

aclaro que puedes usar ***rbind*** o ***bind_row***s

espero te sirva.

Saludos